# Using linux mirror to host 3rd party RPMs

Tags: linux, oracle, rhel, mirror

I'm trying to do something that seems simple in theory, but I can't find the magic search terms for the Google-machine to get any hits.

Basically, we are building a bunch of servers internally (no internet access) so I've created a VM and set up a mirror of our linux distro (Oracle Linux, which is essentially RHEL).  The steps I are here for reference:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/yum-repo-setup-1659167.html

This is fine, but I'd also like to have access to a few other RPMs (e.g. Chrome, vsftpd etc) that aren't part of the standard distribution, but have to be separately downloaded.

The question is, is there any way to simply "include" these rpms with the mirror that I've already set up?  Or do I have to mirror those repos separately?  i.e. is there some place I can just drop an rpm and have it found when someone uses my mirror to do "yum install myprogram"

I hope I've explained this ok.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is make a separate folder, download the required packages and make a repository with the `createrepo` command.

Then you need to create a new repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d for your new repo just like in the referenced howto:

```
[<channel_label>]
name=<Channel Description>
baseurl=http://<repository_server>/yum/<repository path>
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY
enabled=1
```